# JWT authentication and permission_callback

Tags: php, wordpress, angular, rest

In angular, I have following to get the JWT token for wordpress.

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
...
logIn(){
  let loginInfo ={
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'password.'
  };   

  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
              
  this.http.post(
      this.apiURL + 'wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token'
    , loginInfo
    , { headers: headers}
    ).subscribe(
      data => { this.token = data['token']; }
    , err => { console.log(err); }
    );
};
```

Here, I get a successful `token` for the logged in user.

To access a custom endpoint, I am sending the token as following:

```
Test() {
  let test = this.apiURL + 'wp-json/test/v1/test';
  let headers = new HttpHeaders(
    {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    , 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
    }
  );

  this.http.get(test,{headers: headers})
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

### In the php

```php
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ($data) {
    register_rest_route( 'test/v1', '/test/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'testFunction',
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
        }
    ) );
} );
    
function testFunction($data) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    return $user_id;
};

?>
```

However I am still get `forbidden` error:

```json
{
  code: "rest_forbidden",
  message: "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.",
}
```

My understanding is that using `permission_callback` I can check the user authentication.

Ultimately, I am trying to get the `loggedin` user id.

What am I missing?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: something change if you do `return TRUE;` in `permission_callback` ?

Comment: According to ie https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/299843/136493 you need a `nonce` next to `token`. I get a valid response using an Application Password with a header containing `'Authorization' => "Basic " . base64_encode(USER . ':' . PASS)` which is without the nonce as we always login :-/